# How to lead a TabBar Item to a particularly view

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I have a flow map like this:

```
 - EntryView
 |
 - TabBar - NavigationController - FirstView - FirstSubview
          |
          - SecondView
```

When I go to from the FirstSubView to the SecondView is all fine.
But when I want to go back to the FirstView by tapping the tab bar item the FirstSubview appears.
I want that the FirstView appears. How I have to solved the problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: what are you using `storyboard` or `uiview` ??

Comment: I use the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pop the FirstSubview from the navigation stack by implementing

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

in your FirstSubview.
However I haven't yet tried out what happens if you push the back button of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITabBarDelegate` and this method..

`- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item`

to caught tab selections. When tab is selected, you can load the first view.

Comment: I have a customized TabBarController with this method, but I don't know what I have to implement. If I use 'popToRootViewControllerAnimated' nothing happens.